# applying casting in the return of a function in java?

Tags: java, type-conversion, return-type

I just wrote this simple methode that must return a double value. It's a function to withdraw money from the bank account. The function must let the user get the money only if he entries a value smaller than his the amount of money he has in his account.
There is a condition where, if he is a special user, he can take the money even if he tries a value = balance+1000.

As I'm a beginner to java, I'm not yet familiar with this thing of types (I'm a php programmer, so I never really had to worry about this, but I'm getting troubles to make this code work, because I'm returning a double, if it's ok, but a false, if it's not, and I can't do this in java.. This is my methode.. (the variables 'balance' and 'special' belongs to my class).

```
public double getMoney (double value) {
    if (value <= balance) {
        balance = balance - value;
    } else {
        if (special == true && value < (balance+1000)) {
            return balance-value;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's a noob question, but I just started studying java and I was used to code using PHP, where I don't need to worry about the type of my variables, so I was wondering if you could give me some advices.
Thanks

Comment: How about returning a negative number as a boolean false (by checking if the returned value if negative)? You certainly can't mix booleans and doubles.

Comment: o.O.. You're returning two totally incomatible values from the same method?

Comment: @RohitJain, this is my key doubt.. I didn't know I have to worry about the type of my return method.. I didn't while using php.. but well.. different languages.. this is one new thing I learned today :D

Comment: You should definitely loose the habit of returning different types from a method when you move to Java.  A method should return one type and only one type in Java world.

Comment: I noticed it, @jahroy. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Keyser :  When a negative amount is a valid result I wouldn't recommend returning a negative value to mean optional!

Comment: @plasma147 Maybe Integer.MIN_VALUE. If he wants to keep the general structure there isn't much wiggle room :p

Comment: @periback if you used my solution please accept (CheckBox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, instead of false.
Then the caller explictly checks for that value, and detects ist as invalid withDrawn().

The caller checks that by

```
double val = getMoney(5000000);
if (val == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
   // money could not be withdran
   // print message
} else {
   // ok money could be withdrawn
}
```

If you want to do that more professional you would have to retun a transactionInfo:

```
TransActionInfo info = getMoney(500000);
if (info.getStatus == Status.LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
   // could not withraw

} else {
   ...
}
```

Instead of the if you could use a switch statement:

```
TransActionInfo info = getMoney(500000);
switch (info.getStatus()) {
  case: Status.OK: 
     break;
  case Status.LIMIT_EXCEEDED:
    // inform on display of bankomat. or similar
     break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: or NaN. This will likely cause bad side effects earlier.

Comment: Only if you want to store that to a DataBase. NaN is the most dangerous of all ;-)

Comment: how do I check for it later?

Comment: Throwing an Exception is a far beter approach.

Comment: Exception: Totaly wrong!!!!!!! Exception is for errors, not for normal Business Case where it is usual that the account is on its limit!

Comment: Disagree.  So don't 5 other people so far! This seems like a clunky workaround that will make all the surrounding code messier and more error prone.

Comment: Yes it is not optimal, but Excpetion is even worse, I woul dnot do it that way, but i will not totally rewrite his code.

Comment: Funny how the answer that involves using Exceptions is getting all the up-votes.  There is **nothing** wrong with throwing an Exception in this situation.

Comment: i'm just starting to study java and doing some exercises.. I also think exceptions is a great way, but I haven't studied yet the section about exceptions in java, this is why, for this case, @AlexWien was a faster solution (for me, begginer).

Comment: Beware of choosing solutions because they're _fast_ or because they appear to be the _easiest_ way at the time.

Comment: Read Josh Bloch: Effective Java second Edition: Item 57: use Excpetions only for exceptional conditions

Comment: @jahrouy He is playing around to learn java, A real money withdrawal will work totally different (Using BigDecimal, etc.). The code is safe, the are no side effects if you use it as I posted it.

Comment: Fair enough.  The use of Exceptions is certainly worthy of debate as well.  I don't believe there is a correct answer, reather two schools of thought.

Comment: No there is, look at my new solution for professionals; you have to log why it could not be withdrawn, then you need an Status id, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for **money values**, using a double is usually a bad idea. You certainly don't want a loss in precision happen, right?

Try looking into decimal types, such as BigDecimal, or consider using cents stored in a large enough integer type (if you do not need to support fraction of a cent values).

Don't return `false`. Return either `0` ("no money withdrawn"), or use **exceptions** for error handling. Even in loosely typed languages such as PHP or JavaScript this usually is a bad idea, because it causes unexpected behaviour. Try to be **strict** whereever possible!

Another user suggested to use `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`. You might as well use `Double.NaN` but I strongly advise against this. It will make things go wrong in a very *subtle* way, and that is not what you want. You probably want a big fat exception. You **do** want the user of the `getMoney` function to handle this case, so I recommend using an exception that actually *must* be handled by whoever calls `getMoney`.

Comment: exceptions seems to be a good idea... I just have to learn how it works in java.. but i'll get there..

Comment: No Excpetion is for errors only, not for normal businnes case. This is not what excpetions are made for! It is normal that the account is on its limit, This not an exceptional case!. Exception would be when the account number does not exist. Further an Exception will add an enormous slow down, thats why Exeption on some systems (ios) are not fine. But for java it is ok.

Comment: Read Josh Bloch:  Effective Java second Edition: Item 57: use Excpetions only for exceptional conditions

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pass as a method parameter all your variables. So, in the method scope, you solve your question and return true or false ... or return nothing (void).

```
public boolean hasMoney(double need, double balance, boolean special) {
    if( special ) {
        return balance+1000 >= need;
    } else {
        return balance >= need;
    }
}
```

if the return was true, you know that the customer has enoght money

Comment: You missed boolean as the return type